# Case Condition issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, case

I am trying to create a case condition where it removes last characters in a string based on condition.

```
ON im.LegacyItem =
CASE
When
right(tr.item,4) = '_old' then left(tr.item,len(tr.item)-4)
when 
tr.item <> im.legacyitem then left(tr.item,len(tr.item) -2)     
else tr.item
end 
AND im.Location=loc.LocationNo
```

I am getting following error.

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

but when I use only  `right(tr.item,4) = '_old' then left(tr.item,len(tr.item)-4)`

I have no issues.

But, when I use

```
when  tr.item <> im.legacyitem then left(tr.item,len(tr.item) -2)
```

Then I am getting the error above

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see the data so I'm going to guess one of your strings is smaller than or equal to 4 characters. Try doing a select all where the length is less than or equal to

Comment: Then some of the when  tr.item <> im.legacyitem then left(tr.item,len(tr.item) -2) are shorter than 2

Comment: Definitely you have some `tr.item` that are 2 or less characters. So you when you do the math you end up with `left(tr.item, -1)` and since you can't take the left most -1 characters from a string, you get an error. Perhaps change your thing to say `... WHEN tr.item <> im.legacyitem AND len(tr.item)>=2 THEN left(tr.item, len(tr.item)-2) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result could be because the value is less than 2 characters long.
You can find if there are any values shorter than 2 using:

```
SELECT tr.item WHERE len(tr.item) <= 2 FROM 'your source'
```

you could also check the length before casting:

```
((len(tr.item) >= 2) AND (tr.item <> 'NotEqual')) then left(tr.item,len(tr.item) -2)
```

or by adding another 'when' clause before the existing two.

Let me know if that works